# web view illegal interface qualifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

working in Xcode, I am trying to put a second web view into my app, but keep getting an illegal interface qualifier message.

Here is my implementation file:

```
#import "XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController.h"

@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController ()
@synthesize webView;
@end

@implementation XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs103/en/"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

...and my interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

I would REALLY appreciate some help here, if anyone can!

Cheers in advance!

---

### Heading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to remove

```
@synthesize webView;
```

Please replace

```
@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController ()
@synthesize webView;
@end
```

with

```
@interface XYZBonBonoftheDayViewController ()

@end
```

in your implementation file.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried this, but nothing is coming up in my WebView when I run the app in the simulator. Do you happen to know why this might be?

Comment: Have you added Webview in Xib ? Have you linked up Dataset & delegate for webview in XIB ? And please change [webView loadRequest:requestURL]; to [self.webView loadRequest:requestURL];

Comment: No, none of the tutorials I have used mention that. I will give it a go, thanks :)

Comment: Go through this tutorial for both case using storyboard or by programmatically.. http://hayageek.com/uiwebview-uiwebviewdelegate-tutorial/